Spring Data JPA @Query annotation is taking query as string but not as query
I have this repository which extends JPA Repository. Method(findBySearchQuery) defined in the interface implements @Query annotation from Spring Data JPA. The query inside annotation is considered as String but not as query.
package com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository;

import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.model.Restaurant;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends JpaRepository<Restaurant, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r FROM RESTAURANT r WHERE lower(r.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%')) " +
            "OR lower(r.cuisineType) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%'))" )
    List<Restaurant> findBySearchQuery(String query);

    Restaurant findByOwnerId(Long userId);
}

Service file
package com.QuickBite.QuickBite.Service;

import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.model.Restaurant;

import java.util.List;

public interface RestaurantService {

    public List<Restaurant> searchRestaurant(String keyword);


}

Service implementation file containing findBySearchQuery Method
package com.QuickBite.QuickBite.Service;

import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.model.Restaurant;
import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RestaurantServiceImp implements RestaurantService{

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;


    @Override
    public List<Restaurant> searchRestaurant(String keyword) {
        return restaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(keyword);
    }

}

I am getting below all exceptions.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restaurantRepository': Error creating bean with name 'restaurantRepository' defined in com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.QuickBite.QuickBite.QuickBiteApplication.main(QuickBiteApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantRepository' defined in com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:292) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository.RestaurantRepository.findBySearchQuery(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:60) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'RESTAURANT'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:860) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy128.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'RESTAURANT'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.resolveRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2124) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2054) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$RootEntityContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEntityWithJoins(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2024) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitFromClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2011) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1243) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1035) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2132) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1020) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2003) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:802) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:852) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 58 common frames omitted

Dependencies in pom.xml file
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
       <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
       <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
       <version>0.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
       <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
       <version>0.12.6</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
       <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>0.12.6</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


You are using JPA so you either write JPQL which uses entities or you write SQL which uses the tables. Currently I have no idea what your query is. If it is JPQL then change RESTAURANT to Restaurant, if it is SQL you need to tell this and add nativeQuery=true.

The default value of the Query annotation is a JPQL query not a native query. You should use an entity name not the table name. Just change RESTAURANT to Restaurant.

You are using JPQl so you have to use entity class name
 @Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE lower(r.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%')) " +
            "OR lower(r.cuisineType) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%'))" )
    List<Restaurant> findBySearchQuery(String query);


Are you using JPQL or plain SQL?
If it's JPQL I am assuming Restaurant is your class name.
package com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository;

import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.model.Restaurant;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends JpaRepository<Restaurant, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE lower(r.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%')) " +
            "OR lower(r.cuisineType) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%'))" )
    List<Restaurant> findBySearchQuery(String query);

    Restaurant findByOwnerId(Long userId);
}

if its plain sql then you need to set nativeQuery=true
package com.QuickBite.QuickBite.repository;

import com.QuickBite.QuickBite.model.Restaurant;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends JpaRepository<Restaurant, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r FROM RESTAURANT r WHERE lower(r.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%')) " +
            "OR lower(r.cuisineType) LIKE lower(concat('%', :query, '%'))" , nativeQuery = true)
    List<Restaurant> findBySearchQuery(String query);

    Restaurant findByOwnerId(Long userId);
}

